# Killing msnodesql connection when socket disconnects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a socket (socket.io) that connects to a MS SQL db on socket connection like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var intervalID;
    sql.open(connStr, function(err,conn){       //open connection to MS SQL db
        if(err)
            console.error("Could not connect to sql: ", err);
```

When the socket disconnects I want to kill that db connection, but there doesn't seem to be a `close()` operation in `msnodesql` module for node.js. How can I close this connection on socket disconnect?

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                //close the MS SQL db connection 
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `conn.close()` that's being called from one of [the test cases](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver/blob/396750b7ff28f18f9f51b1f070a91fbe6046cd7a/test/connect.js#L44).

As an aside: you're opening a new database connection for every new `socket.io` client. Depending on your situation, it might be sufficient to create a single connection and reuse it:

```
// open connection to database
sql.open(connStr, function(err, conn) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start accepting socket.io connections
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // use 'conn' here.
  });
});
```

Comment: That was the root cause of me wanting to close the DB connections. Because I was creating new socket connections every new client there were associated db connections. This was causing a lot of overhead on the db server. Thank you!